# Storing First Letter of Names Into Empty Div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a monogram app for an assignment. The code is supposed to prompt the user for `firstName`, `middleName`, and `lastName`. I am having trouble storing the variables to the div`Initials`and only displaying the first letter of each name. My code is below. Thank you for the help.

```js
function createMonogram() {
    let firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
    document.getElementById("Initials"[0]).innerHTML = firstName[0];
    let middleName = prompt("What is your middle name?");
    document.getElementById("Initials"[1]).innerHTML = middleName[0];
    let lastName = prompt("What is your last name?");
    document.getElementById("Initials"[2]).innerHTML = lastName[0];
}
```

```html
<h1>Chris's Monogram App</h1>

<button onclick="createMonogram()">Create Your Monogram</button>

<div id="Initials"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do:

```js
function createMonogram() {
  let firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
  let middleName = prompt("What is your middle name?");
  let lastName = prompt("What is your last name?");
  document.getElementById("Initials").innerHTML = firstName[0] + ' ' + middleName[0] + ' ' + lastName[0];        
}
```

```html
<h1>Chris's Monogram App</h1>

<button onclick="createMonogram()">Create Your Monogram</button>

<div id="Initials"></div>
```

`document.getElementById("Initials")` gets the div. innerHTML or innerText sets the value in the Div. Using innerHTML is unsafe in general, but i presume you are doing some practice task.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked and yes you are correct. Just doing an assignment for class.

Comment: Feel free to mark their post as an answer if it solves your question :)